# how to resolve hibernate staleStateException

Tags: hibernate

I have a list of records on a page and I keep getting this error when deleting a record from the page on one browser(not saving it) and (saving) the existing records in another browser. I was wondering if there is a way to avoid from getting this exception.

Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [1]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Comment: Actually this exception happens when attempting to update & it doesn't find the row it was meant to update. You mentioned you're deleting from one browser. You're sure you're not accidentally auto-committing it? Log the Hibernate queries to confirm.

Comment: yeah i am pretty sure i am not auto committing.. when i check the data at the database there is no change after the first browser delete because i haven't saved it